# How to print line number with svn blame?

Tags: svn

I did an `svn blame` on a file like

```
$ svn blame folder1/file.txt
```

It gives me the otput that looks like:

```
svnRevision userName line
```

How do I make it to print the line number as well?, something like

```
lineNumber svnRevision userName line
```

Comment: not possible.. wow, the svn really **is** retarded.. :/ I miss git :/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Based on Kunal Cholera, but without creating any files

```
svn blame file.cpp | cat -n
```

Answer (score 5):

you can do that:

```
svn blame file.cpp | nl
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get line numbers by outputting the result in XML

```
svn blame --xml <file>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pipe blame to easiest awk script, which add FNR output to $0. For example:

```
svn blame file.txt | awk '{print FNR $0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out a work around using multiple commands like this:

trick is to use svn blame to blame and then output that to a file, then use cat command with -n to get line numbers on that file and then delete that file.

svn blame abc/HelloWorld.java > file.txt ; cat -n file.txt; rm file.txt

hope that helps !

thanks everyone for responding..

Comment: You don't really need the temporary file. Simply pipe the output of `svn blame` to `cat -n`. (edit: see [Pelle's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593157/how-to-print-line-number-with-svn-blame/11633248#11633248)).

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible with `blame`.

[Possible switches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re02.html):

```
--revision (-r) REV
--username USER
--password PASS
--no-auth-cache
--non-interactive
--config-dir DIR
```